# What's the name of this horror story for kids?

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the name of a story.

It was about dolls that made her parents argue and aggressive for payback, then turned her small so they could do more payback. In the end, she gets to the attic of the doll house and pulls a similar looking doll of herself out, and becomes free.

Comment: When did you read this? In what country? Do you remember any details about whether it was paperback or hardback? Cover details?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think "payback" is the right word, unless she'd burnt their house down or something.  ("Payback" means "revenge", whereas I think you mean they became violent for no particular reason.)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely *[Among the Dolls](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24889.Among_the_Dolls)* by William Sleator now that I've read it:

> When her parents give her a gloomy old dollhouse for her birthday instead of the ten speed bike she's expecting, Vicky is disappointed. But she soon becomes fascinated by the small shadowy world and its inhabitants. The hours she spends playing with the dolls is a good way to escape from her parents's arguments. As Vicky's life becomes more troubled, she starts to take out her frustration on the dolls, making their lives as unhappy as hers. 
>   Then one day, Vicky wakes up inside the dollhouse, trapped among the monsters she's created. Bewildered, Vicky is sure she's dreaming. Can she find her way out of this nightmare world?